# AJAX JQuery not updating span text

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using a star rating script [here](http://www.codexworld.com/star-rating-system-with-jquery-ajax-php/), the script updates my database correctly but the returned text in my spans (avgrat and totalrat) are not updated. The variables in between both span tags should be updated with the returned values.

**Returned value:**

```
echo json_encode($ratingRow);
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <?php echo form_open('http://localhost/mysite/rating/rate'); ?>
  <input name="rating" value="<?php echo $ratingRow['stars']; ?>" id="rating_star" type="hidden" postID="<?php echo $nsid; ?>" />
  <div class="overall-rating">
    Overall Rating of <span id="avgrat"><?php echo $ratingRow['average_rating']; ?></span> Based on <span id="totalrat"><?php  echo $ratingRow['rating_number'] ?></span> votes.
  </div>
  <?php echo form_close(); ?>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#rating_star").codexworld_rating_widget({
      starLength: '5',
      initialValue: $('#rating_star').val(),
      callbackFunctionName: 'processRating',
      imageDirectory: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>i/icon',
      inputAttr: 'postID'
    }); 
  });

  function processRating(val, attrVal){
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>rating/rate',
      data: {'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>', "postID":attrVal, "ratingPoints":val},
      dataType: 'json',
      success : function(data) {
        if (data.status == 'ok') {
          $("span#avgrat").text($(this).data("average_rating"));
          $("span#totalrat").text($(this).data("rating_number"));
        }else{
          alert('Some problem occured, please try again.');
        }
      }
    });
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change these:

```
$("span#avgrat").text($(this).data("average_rating"));
$("span#totalrat").text($(this).data("rating_number"));
```

To these:

```
data = JSON.parse(data);
$("span#avgrat").text(data[0]["average_rating"]);
$("span#totalrat").text(data[0]["rating_number"]);
```

You cannot use `this` there. The `this` there refers to the `success` function. You have to first parse the data using `JSON.parse(data)`. So it becomes a JavaScript Object from a string. **This is optional, as you have already used `dataType: "json"`.** Now it should work for you as expected.

The `data` is an object and not a function. You have used `data("rating_number")`, which should be `data[0]["rating_number"]` and so on. Kindly check the updated answer.

Comment: I updated the script based on your suggestions Praveen, but I receive the following error in Firebug debugger. "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data -- data = JSON.parse(data);" The arrow in Firebug is pointing to the "d" in data.

Comment: Er... Remove the whole line and type it yourself. Looks like some encoding issue. @ReeseB... Else remove that line itself.

Comment: I removed and manually typed in, same error. Could the error be referring to the returned data? Here is the returned data. "{"0":{"rating_number":"1","average_rating":"2.0"},"status":"ok"}"

Comment: @ReeseB I was actually about to ask you that. The `data` seems okay to me.

Comment: @ReeseB Remove the `data = JSON.parse(data);` line and change the other lines as how I have updated.

Comment: @ReeseB Kindly check. I need to leave to another country.

Comment: All the best. Happy New Year. `:)` I am waiting for your reply on how it goes.